# CMS Validation in SXA 1.7.1

Tags: sxa

We are using simple text components in SXA 1.7.1 and we need to validate these text components for maximum length. If this was not SXA we would have put the validations at template level now I want to know what is best approach to do these maximum length validations in SXA.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no OOTB solution to this yet.

Comment: Is there anything you can suggest

Comment: Just a random thought, if its a form accepting user inputs and you want to validate those inputs, may be you can use a WFFM or Sitecore Form (if on SC9) and apply the validations on the fields. Then use _Form Wrapper_ to assign those WFFM/Form items in SXA.

Comment: I submitted a support ticket with Sitecore. Version 1.7.1 does not support custom field level validation for Sxa fields.

Comment: How should we approach validations could you please provide any inputs